# Is there a way in typescript to pass an optional parameter to a constructor only if it exist?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, constructor, optional-parameters

I have an object that has a constructor with an optional parameter like this:

```
class example{

   constructor(a: string,b: string,c: string,d?:string){
     //...
   }

}
```

This class will be instatiated inside another method. Like this:

```
function createExample(a: string,b: string,c: string,d?:string){
  return new example(a,b,c,d)
}
```

But i only want to pass the "d" parameter if the function createExample() received. Is there a way in javascript/typescript to do this. Something like:

I want to pass the parameter d only if it exists, and I hope I don't have to do an if that checks this, because if I have more optional parameters it can get complicated. Is there a way in javascript/typescript to do this. Something like:

```
function createExample(a: string,b: string,c: string,d?:string){
  return new example(a,b,c,d?)
}
```

Or should I just leave the instatiaton with the normal "d" parameter, and in case it is not defined, it should be passed as undefined?

Comment: Where do you get the argument `D` from? What do you mean by "*if it exists*"? What exactly doesn't exist - and why would you not know whether it does?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpg5aN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You are right, I did not explain myself very well. Let me edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should I just leave the instatiaton with the normal "d" parameter, and in case it is not defined, it should be passed as undefined?

Yes, exactly this. JavaScript treats missing arguments and `undefined` being passed as an argument the same<sup>1</sup> - both end up with an `undefined` or defaulted parameter. So it's as simple as

```
function createExample(a: string, b: string, c: string, d?: string) {
  return new Example(a, b, c, d);
}
```

If you really care, you can use spread syntax with an array:

```
function createExample(...args: [a: string, b: string, c: string, d?: string]) {
  return new Example(...args);
}
```

<sub>1: except for `arguments.length` and rest parameter syntax</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you define the type for `D` as potentially undefined, you can just pass it in

```ts
class Example {
   constructor(a: string, b: string, c: string, d?: string) {
     // ...  
   }
}

const A = "";
const B = "";
const C = "";
let D: string | undefined;

if (someCondition) {
  D = "d";
}

const ex = new Example(A, B, C, D);
```